# Add values together to get total

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops

Sorry for the noob question but I am really new to php. So I have this foreach statement:

```
foreach ($contents as &$item) {
    $item->sku  = $item->sku;
    $item->slug     = $item->slug;
    $item->price    = $item->price_per;
    $item->subtotal = $item->qty * $item->price_per;
}
```

It works perfectly to display details about each item, but how to I get a total price? 
The $item->subtotal for each item added together

Comment: You have 3 nearly identical (and correct) answers to choose from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have a variable dedicated to keeping track of the total:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($contents as &$item) {
    $item->sku  = $item->sku;
    $item->slug     = $item->slug;
    $item->price    = $item->price_per;
    $item->subtotal = $item->qty * $item->price_per;
    $total += $item->subtotal;
}
```

All this does is initialize a tracking variable with an initial value of zero. It then adds the new calculated subtotal to it in each iteration. At the end you have your grand total.

Comment: Um, you may not have noticed but I posted mine first

Comment: @ciuak Yes he did.  Our answers were very close, but John Conde's was first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating a variable outside the loop with the latest subtotal?

```
$grandTotal = 0;
foreach ($contents as &$item) {
    $item->sku  = $item->sku;
    $item->slug     = $item->slug;
    $item->price    = $item->price_per;
    $item->subtotal = $item->qty * $item->price_per;
    $grandTotal += $item->subtotal;
}

print($grandTotal);  // Hopefully a positive monetary value :)
```

Comment: our answers are identical!

Comment: @ciuak Yes, such is a side effect of multiple posters typing up an answer only seconds apart.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($contents as &$item) {
    $item->sku  = $item->sku;
    $item->slug     = $item->slug;
    $item->price    = $item->price_per;
    $item->subtotal = $item->qty * $item->price_per;
    $total += $item->subtotal;
}
```

Comment: Since all answers and the same I selected yours cause you answered first.

Comment: @awsm Actually John Conde answered first according to timestamps.

Comment: I know that I was last